# Weblogic : disable user-lockout on specific managed servers

Tags: weblogic

1 of the powerful features of weblogic is the user-lockout mechanism in the security realms.
In our case this is very useful, but there is 1 but...

On some of our managed servers, all (HTTP) users are expected to use the same username/password,
so if user-lockout is enabled, and 1 of the users would send a wrong password a couple of times, user-lockout will kick in, and ALL the users that use this username will be locked out.
(even those that did send the correct username/password combination)

The ideal scenario for me would be to be able to disable the userlockout feature on those specific managed servers, and to keep it enabled on others.

Is there a way to achieve this, via a startup argument or WLST command?

Any hints would be appreciated

Thx   Jo

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in the console, under the default realm -> configuration -> user lockout. Here's the documentation (I'm assuming wls 12c):
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/domain.htm#SECMG414